# Counting amount of textareas

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a page where the user can create new textareas to fill in by clicking a button. I want to count the amount of textareas the user has created. Any idea of how to do this using js?

This is what I have tried:

```
var txt = document.querySelectorAll('textarea .alternativ').length;
```

Comment: Sure, but SO isn't a free code writing service. Please post your code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all textareas in the document by using `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')`. This returns an array containing all elements of the textarea type. All arrays have a property `length` telling us how many items it contains. `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').length` will give you the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with jQuery:

```
var textareas = $('textarea').length;
```

or in pure JS:

```
var textareas = (document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')).length
```